# I can not see Team Foundation Server in powerbuilder?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, powerbuilder

I install visual studio team explorer 2013 and also i installed the Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2013 and 2015 MSSCCI.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2013&2015 MSSCCI Provider 32-bit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer20132015M) is not installed correctly. So, please try to reinstall it based on the requirements.

Check the **System Requirements** to install the MSSCCI Provider:

> 1. 32-bit Operating System
>
>    - Windows 8.1, Windows 8, Windows 7, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2008 R2
> 2. Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2005, 2008, 2010,
>      2012, or 2013
> 3. Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 or Team Explorer 2013

I tested on my side with below steps and I can see the Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider:

1. Install **PowerBuilder 2017**
2. Install **Team Explorer 2013**
3. Install the **MSSCCI Provider**

Refer to [Using PowerBuilder 2017 with TFS source control](https://community.appeon.com/groups/powerbuilder/using-powerbuilder-2017-tfs-source-control) for details.

[image]